# ¿Cómo configurar el log4j.xml, para que dependiendo la acción envíe un registro a archivos diferentes?

Tags: java, log4j

Quisiera crear dos logs, uno para desarrollo y otro para efectos generales, y en el de desarrollo enviar todas las operaciones errores e información generada por el aplicativo; en el otro log, solo la información que sigue el programa.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="Appender1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"/>
       </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="Appender2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="D:/Logs/SpringMVC2.log" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"/>
       </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Appender1" />
        <appender-ref ref="Appender2" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Normalmente se trabajan con niveles de log, suelen ser suficientes. Cuando estás en la etapa de desarrollo configuras el nivel más alto que es `debug`, de otra manera trabajas solo con `info` y antes de implantar el sistemas cambias el nivel para que el log solo registre lo necesario. ¿Aun así necesitas ficheros separados?

Comment: Sí, es por fines de negocio, debe realizarse el log en dos archivos.

Comment: Revisa si esto te funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652239/4326551